# How to make Visual Studio Code to mark errors in time?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an Angular project and I noticed that when I modify some file and it affects other files, VS Code doesn't mark the files with errors in red until I open that files. How can I make the editor to mark in red the files with errors without entering the files that I changed?

An example if you don't understand me:

I have an interface and a class implementing that interface. Let's say they are called IService and Service respectively.
So I decide to change the name of one method of IService. Obviously, Service has an error: it isn't implementing all the methods from IService, but the file of Service shows in red when I open it. I need it to mark with red the moment I change the method of IService, so I don't have to guess where there is an error.

NodeJS helps a lot because it shows the errors in console, but I would prefer VS Code to mark them. Is it possible?